# SSIS Redirect Row Hanging / Frozen / Not Working

Tags: redirect, ssis

I have an SSIS package written in Visual Studio 2013. I am attempting to parse a flat text file. If any of the columns are truncated or cannot be casted to the corresponding data type, I want to redirect these rows to a Script Component and then dump the data into a SQL Server table.

When I debug this package, the redirect rows step is hanging. I see the yellow spinning icon and nothing happens. Down in the status bar, it says that the "Package execution completed", but it didn't. There aren't any errors in the Progress tab.

Do you know why the "Redirect Row" is freezing? I have placed breakpoints in the "Set Error Description" script component and they are not being hit. So, it looks like the "Redirect Row" has crashed/raised an exception.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Click on your Progress tab. Snap a picture of that. I suspect you have a failure somewhere

Comment: @billinkc I've added a screen shot of the progress tab. As mentioned in the description, I don't see any errors on the progress tab. Do you see something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be with missing columns in my flat file. If I configured that the file has 10 columns in the flat file manager, but then the file only has 8 columns, when there is a truncation or data type exception, SSIS will hang when attempting to redirect rows.

To resolve this issue I changed the property of the “AlwaysCheckForRowDelimiters” to False on the flat file connection manager.